# urlMatcherFactory compile URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I want to parse URL params to the object, using urlMatcherFactory.

URL:

```
/home/1?param1=tt
```

JS:

```
var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/home/:id?param1&param2");
var matched = urlMatcher.exec($location.url());
```

After executing this code I get only 1 field: id with value `1?param1=tt`

In this case I am expecting to get 2 fields: id ==> 1 and param1 ==> tt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse URL search parameters, we have to pass those params separably to exec function:

```
var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/home/:id?param1&param2");
var matched = urlMatcher.exec($location.path(), $location.search());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read comments at [urlMatcherFactory](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/urlMatcherFactory.js) file, you can see the following comments to parse query parameters at URL:

```
/*
 * Wraps an existing custom Type as an array of Type, depending on 'mode'.
 * e.g.:
 * - urlmatcher pattern "/path?{queryParam[]:int}"
 * - url: "/path?queryParam=1&queryParam=2
 * - $stateParams.queryParam will be [1, 2]
 * if `mode` is "auto", then
 * - url: "/path?queryParam=1 will create $stateParams.queryParam: 1
 * - url: "/path?queryParam=1&queryParam=2 will create $stateParams.queryParam: [1, 2]
*/
```

So, I think you need to use the urlMatcher as the following:

```
var matched = urlMatcher.exec($location.url(), {mode: 'auto'});
```

Read more about [URL-Routing#urlmatcherfactory-and-urlmatchers](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlmatcherfactory-and-urlmatchers)

Comment: Unfortunately mode: 'auto' didn't change anything.